# How to convert an int to display as datetime?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012, ssms

How to convert below int to display as datetime in ssms

'201061311912'

Comment: And what datetime do you want for this?

Comment: this format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm

Comment: Trying to work out: is the year 2010 and the month 61?? Or is the year 6131?? Or is the year 61 and the time 31:19:12?? @GordonLinoff you spotted the missing 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `datetimefromparts()`, perhaps, if your string is in the format YYYYMMDDHHMMSS:

```
select datetimefromparts(left(str, 4), substring(str, 5, 2), substring(str, 7, 2),
                         substring(str, 9, 2), substring(str, 11, 2), substring(str, 13, 2), 0)
from (values ('20100613011912')) as v(str);
```

This is not exactly the format in your question, but it might be what you intend.

Comment: If you have a lot of rows to do this for in one query I suggest converting Linoff's query to a function.

Comment: How do you convert them into a function?

Comment: @Jason312 . . . I user-defined function would just slow things down.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am missing something, couldn't this be as simple as this?

```
select cast(format(20100613011912,'####-##-## ##:##:##') as datetime)
```